# not able to decrypt anymore

Tags: android, security

I was using the below code in my app for encrypting and decrypting passwords. It was working fine until suddenly I noticed it fail. The only change I remember doing is to update my ADT and eclipse a few days ago to latest version. Not sure why is it failing now. It works if I create new encryptions. But if I use any encrypted password which was generated earlier and pass it to the code below for decrypting, then the error comes. It is failing in the line "byte[] plainBytes = cipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);"

My decryption code below

```
        String keyword  = "keyword";
        int iterationCount = 1000; 
        int keyLength = 256;
        String[] fields = encryptedPassword.split("]");
        byte[] salt = fromBase64(fields[0]);
        byte[] cipherBytes = fromBase64(fields[1]);
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(keyword.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount, keyLength);
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC");
        SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        PBEParameterSpec pbeSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, pbeSpec);
        byte[] plainBytes = cipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);
        plainStr = new String(plainBytes, "UTF-8").trim();
        return plainStr;
```

and the error I am getting is below

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
```

Can anyone please help here

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what the problem was. I had updated the jdk version from 1.6 to 1.7. That was the culprit. Since I am using javax.crypto classes, any version change was causing the encryption also to slightly change.

Comment: well, after posting my answer, I did further testing and found that jdk version is not the issue. Still trying to figure out the issue

Comment: have been able to resolve it for now. I had set the ADT installation fresh and then it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no security expert, but I believe `PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC` is PKCS #12, whereas you're deriving keys using PKCS #5. Perhaps if you need to provide the same algorithm into `Cipher.getInstance()`.